# How to get 3 different Class Element to display in single memo field in table row order

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from a web page within the comment section.  There are three comment section labeled by ClassName of "odd", "Comment" and "null" separated by .  What I am trying to do is populate the data into a text field in my form but to keep the  order in tact. Also a bonus would be to add a space or tab to separate each .

I am able to export to three different fields but I would rather have everything populated into a single comment field on my form.

HMTL Code

```
    <tr id="4178695" class="null">

        <td>Date: 03/20/2017 14:37</td>
            <td>Tech: Wood, Ken</td>
            <td>Process Order. <br/>-Direct-00:15-Inquiry<br/>-Indirect-00:15-Paperwork</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="4011079" class="odd">

        <td>Date: 12/19/2016 14:45</td>
            <td>Tech: Pine, Al</td>
            <td>Quarterly Contact: Left VM for and sent f/u email.<br/>-Direct-00:15-Phone</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3394536" class="Comment">

            <td>Date: 09/29/2016 12:09</td>
            <td>Tech: Fosgate, Rockford</td>
        <td>9/28/2016: Sent email to family providing new contact number. <br/>-Direct-00:15-Other</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="4178695" class="null">

        <td>Date: 08/20/2016 14:37</td>
            <td>Tech: Wood, Ken</td>
            <td>Process Order. <br/>-Direct-00:15-Inquiry<br/>-Indirect-00:15-Paperwork</td>

    </tr>

    <tr id="3394536" class="Comment">

            <td>Date: 07/29/2016 12:09</td>
            <td>Tech: Fosgate, Rockford</td>
        <td>9/28/2016: Sent email to family providing new contact number. <br/>-Direct-00:15-Other</td>
    </tr>
```

VBA Code

```
    Dim t, u, v As String
    Set oColl = doc.getElementsByClassName("odd")
    Set oColl2 = doc.getElementsByClassName("Comment")
    Set oColl3 = doc.getElementsByClassName("null")

    For Each o In oColl
        t = t & "Odd: " & o.innerText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next

    For Each p In oColl2
        u = u & "Comment: " & p.innerText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next

    For Each q In oColl3

    v = v & "Null: " & q.innerText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Next

    Screen.ActiveForm.MessageBox = "Most Recent Comments: " & vbCrLf & t & vbCrLf & u & vbCrLf & v
```

The code above works but in spits out each comment by cycling through each  ClassName label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all TR elements of the TABLE with comments:

`Set table = doc.getElementById("tableid")`

or

`Set table = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0]`.

Then iterate all rows (`tr`) by using `table.children`, optionally filtering by class name (`className` property).

## Update

Here is a more complete example:

```
    Set doc = IE.Document
    Set table = doc.getElementById("commentTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For Each row In table
        Set cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each cell in cells
            r = r & cell.innerText & vbTab
        Next cell

        r = r & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next row
```

Comment: Tried the following but nothing is populating except for "Most Recent Comments: "

Comment: `Dim table As Object, htmlcomment As Object`


 `Dim r As String`

    `Set doc = IE.Document`

    `Set table=doc.getElementsByTagName("commentTable").getElementsByTagName("tr") `

    `For Each htmlcomment In table`
    `r = r & htmlcomment.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText `
    `Next `

`Screen.ActiveForm.MessageBox = "Most Recent Comments: " & vbCrLf & r `

Comment: Is `commentTable` ID or class name? Please note that `getElementsByTagName` searches for name of tag, like <`table`> or <`tr`>, and also `getElementsBy*` functions return arrays, so you would have to add index `(1)` afterwards to get the first element (or other).

Comment: <`table cellspacing="0" id="commentTable" summary=""`>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successful pull the data with the following code:

```
    Dim table As Object, htmlcomment As Object
    Dim r As String

    Set doc = IE.Document
    Set table = doc.getElementById("commentTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")

    For Each htmlcomment In table
    r = r & htmlcomment.innerText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Next

    Screen.ActiveForm.MessageBox = "Most Recent Comments: " & vbCrLf & r
```

Now, I just have to figure out how to add a space or tab to separate the <`TD`>.